# Has anyone solved the problem of a Facebook app, restricted for TOS failures, related to log in failures, that you cannot recreate?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Facebook has restricted our app for violating their TOS -- as far as we can tell the issue is only related to the Android app. They say it's crashing and creating a bad user experience.

However, we cannot recreate the failure and have no idea what is causing the problem -- making it very hard to fix.

Facebook gave us a list of tests to run - when we test, we pass every one.

Has anyone had this problem? If so, any idea how to recreate the problem or what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

If Facebook restricts your Android app (and only Android), for TOS issues related to crashing during login and you cannot recreate the issue.

Try installing and logging into the Facebook Android app before testing your app.

We had a terrible time with this until someone tried this -- the second we tested with the Facebook app running we experienced the problem.

The problem had to do with a hash in our app -- which has to be entered in the Android settings in your Facebook App (https://developers.facebook.com/). It's just copy and paste.

This leads one to suspect that Facebook is only checking the hash if their app is also running.